# Is it possible to conditionally display DocuSign template parts/sections?

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to know if it is possible to show/hide parts of DocuSign document template depending on the data which is passed in as a request.

I already have document template created and uploaded to DocuSign. I then use templateId to create envelope for that document and I also send some data (as json) to prepopulate certain fields inside the envelope.

The thing I am asking now is:
If the template has, let's say, 3 paragraphs, is it possible to hide one of them completely, based on the passed in json data?

Creating and uploading multiple templates is not an option due to large number of conditionally displayed sections.

I have been reading DocuSign API documentation, but couldn't find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you will have to use Responsive Signing. 
This feature change the format of the document you sign from PDF to HTML.
With HTML being the format, there are a lot more things you can do.
For example, you can use what we call "Smart Sections" which is exactly what you want. Sections that can be shown off/on based on logic you set.
Find out more about the responsive signing API here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/responsive-signing/api-overview